# Not Vanishing Set of a Global Section Affine

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring, $X$ a proper $R$-scheme, $\mathcal{L}$ an ample sheaf and $s \in \Gamma(X, \mathcal{L})$ a global section.

Two questions:

1. Why is the open set $X_s := \{x \in X | s_a \neq 0 \}$ **affine**?
2. Is $X_s$ affine under weaker conditions? (for example if $X$ not proper or $\mathcal{L}$ not ample)

Comment: If $\mathcal{L}$ is not ample, there is no chance : take $X=\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{L}=\mathcal{O}_X$ and $s$ the constant section $1$. Then $X_s=\mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: This is false in general, if $s=0$, so please be more specific. It will also fail even if $s\neq 0$, but zero on some components. I think I know what you have in mind, but do not want to go back and forth if I am wrong.

Comment: @Mohan If $s=0$, then $X_s=\emptyset$ which is affine.

Comment: @Roland You are right. If $s$ is a section of $L$, then $s^n$ is a section of $L^n$ for all $n>0$. Also, $X_s=X_{s^n}$. Thus, you may assume $L$ is very ample. So, you get an embedding $X\subset \mathbb{P}^k_R$ as a closed subscheme with $s^n=0$ a hyperplane. So, the complement is a closed subset of $\mathbb{A}^k_R$, which says it is affine.